# Is "aka" used in some instances to mean "meaning" more than "also known as"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, slang, abbreviations

I am a native English speaker, and I recently realized that I use "aka" in sentences where substituting "also known as" wouldn't make complete sense. For example, I might say or message

- "This event is going to be fancy...aka you probably shouldn't wear that outfit."

In this instance, "aka" could be substituted by "meaning" but not by "also known as." Is this a common usage in informal English, or is this peculiar?

Comment: did you try searching for it just to see if it's already out there?

Comment: It looks like an extensive, jocular usage of aka.

Comment: It's just a modern slang.

Comment: See also:https://7esl.com/aka/

Comment: I've never heard anybody say this. Accents vary, you know, so are you sure they aren't **really** saying *ahah!* or *aquí* or *a key* or *a cay* or *a caye* or   *huh-uh!* or *ack huh* or *aqua* or *haha* or *acker* or *hacker* or *haggard* or *hookah* or *harrumph*?   Maybe it was the middle part of *j**ack-o’**-lantern* or *amnesi**ac ah**ead* or *hurr**ah Co**lleen*? :)

Comment: @WritingShort Because *slang* is not a count noun, you cannot have “❌a slang“ or in fact “any ❌slangs” at all. I suppose that maybe, just maybe, when comparing, say, street slang versus shop slang,  you be said to be comparing different “❓slangs”, but that would mean two different collections of slang expressions, as unusual as comparing two different “rices” would be. Normally we would just compare two kinds of rice. Or two kinds of slang. You can use it attributively to create slang expressions if you want, though.

Comment: @tchrist, I've heard many people say this, but not in many (~20) years.  What they (and I) said was clearly /eɪkeɪeɪ/, not /ækə/.  I never saw anyone write this down, nor did I ever discuss the term with anyone, but I assumed from the start that everyone was saying *AKA*, because the pronunciation was identical, and because the meaning made sense.

Comment: @Juhasz Oh right. It must have been the expected /ˈækə/ pronunciation for that would-be ***aka*** word there that sounded so uncomfortably weird in my head.  If I had seen it written ***A. K. A.***, then I would surely have heard it as [eɪ̯ʔkʰe(ɪ̯)ˈʔej] or [eɪ̯kɛˈjej] et cetera, and so thought nothing of it. :) The OED has /ˌeɪkeɪˈeɪ/ for it. They have a secondary sense of it: "In extended use: introducing an alternative description of or name for an object or activity".

Comment: @tchrist - why the down and close votes? If this new connotation  is not present in dictionaries  apart from the paywalled OED, how could a user look for its new usage? I think the OP asked in the right, though unwelcoming, place.

Comment: @user66974 You have to ask the people who did those things.

Comment: @user66974, the OP said 'I recently realized that I use "aka"' in this way, without giving any indication that anybody else does. If the question provided some reason to believe that there exists a pattern of such usage (even if only by including something like 'I have heard people use "aka" this way'), this would be a reasonable question. Note that tchrist said 'I've never heard anybody say this' and he is not alone in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extensive usage  of aka (also known as) is not yet present in dictionaries, not even in Urban Dictionary. A few sites, anyway, note that:

> AKA can also be used in similar way to "i.e." (id est in Latin, which translates best as "that is" but used to mean "in other words"). For example:
> *Terry Baxter aka the best-looking flirt in town will be there so leave your daughters at home.*

([Cyber Definitions: What Does AKA Mean?](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/AKA.html))

Comment: It’s in the paywalled OED [here](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/306290). Reminds me of *viz.* or *namely*.

Comment: While the first sentence of the quotation may seem to sanction the usage that the question is about, it should be noted that the example it offers is different from what the OP is interested in. In the Terry Baxter example *aka* can be replaced with *also known as*, while the OP is specifically asking about the the cases where such substitution is not possible.

Comment: 'In other words' can be used to introduce a paraphrase etc, or, stretching, a related recommendation / deduction ["She said the movie was a bit predictable." ...  "In other words, she didn't like it." [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20other%20words)]] // 'Stated or **interpreted** another way' [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_other_words)]